# display two UIViews and search display controller in one view

Tags: iphone, uiview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `uiview` with a button on that. When click on that button i am showing a `subview`.

The  subview contains a `table view` and a `search display controller`. when i enter something on search bar it will be showing the search result `tableview`.

once search is done and going back to the superview and again come back to subview, the table view that displays all the records is not scrollable and also the search bar contains the text that has been  entered before, that is search bar contains text but the `tableview` is not search result table view.

This issue will not come if i click on Cancel button of searchbar, without clicking on cancel button if i go back to superview, the issue arises.

Answer (score 0):

When you show yourTableview with searchBar at that time set bellow code..

```
searching = NO; // if you use this BOOL value..
```

and also clear the text of UISearchBar's text i.e.

```
searchBar.text = @"";
```

and after reloadData of `UITableView`

```
-(void)showSearchTable   // its an example
{
     searching = NO;
     searchBar.text = @"";
     [yourTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: but ViewWillAppear will not get called when we hide and show the view correct?

Comment: but you say when i go back and push again at that time you see the text in textfield and data not display proper so i give u this logic but tell me what is the main pro?? what u want??

Comment: oh sorry sorry i understand now just do this coding when you click on any button which through you show the searchbar tableview..

Comment: going back means hiding and showing subview.I am staying on the same view controller...

Comment: Dear, when you show the tablview with searchbar at that time first clear the searchbar text is clear and reload table .. try this ...

Comment: hi..i want to perform the same action that happens when click on cancel button of search bar on my button click.i dont know what all things happen when click on cancel button..